# kGAIScreenName of Google Analytics for iOS v3 is undeclared?

Tags: ios, google-analytics-api

Today, I found GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK have new 3.0 version in Cocoapods. I upgraded and I try to modified the code of manual screen measurement as below:

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Detail View"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

However, I always get error about kGAIScreenName is undeclared. Even I add GAIFields.h header, it still not work.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You have to include two more things:

```
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

Checking what's in `GAIFields.h` I can see that `kGAIScreenName` is there:

```
extern NSString *const kGAIScreenName;   // synonym for kGAIDescription
```

Might be important point that the current Google Analytics is in beta, so using the latest downloadable SDK is always a good idea. What I tried and what is working currently for me is `Version: 3.0 (August 16, 2013)`.

Comment: Thanks. I exactly added GAIFields.h, and I used to use Cocoapods to manage the GA library instead of downloadable SDK. 

Now, I downgrade back to 2.0beta4. I will use this, until experts fix it. ^^

Comment: I also experienced different problems with new Google Analytics SDK: for me using the screenName setting does not work in viewDidAppeare, it is not reporting the screen usage towards Google. I managed to have a solution for this particular problem, so if you need more help, just comment here.

Comment: @codedad as I am facing that same problem and wondering why the screenName won't get sent to Google I am quite curious about your solution - would you mind posting it? thanks a lot

Comment: seems my issue wasn't all that different to your answer and got resolved by it..thanks

Comment: @hajn: glad to hear it is resolved now. If you need my solution to screenName issue lately here it is: I had to use lower level SDK call.  id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
 [tracker set:kGAIScreenName
     value:@"CardsView"];
 [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];

Comment: i wasated 2 hours and then fine this solution. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I am using a hardcoded value of @"&cd" for kGAIScreenName and it works perfectly. Found the value in the Measurement Protocol documentation at Google https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#apptracking