# Google ios analytics not working for few screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd integrated Google analytics in my app. It is working fine for few screens but not for few other screens(ie, viewcontrollers).

**Totally I have 45 screens, but the GAI works only for 19 screens.** I'd followed the steps in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/).

I'd changed as below in all viewcontrollers,

```
@interface Myviewcontroller : GAITrackedViewController
```

and imported `GAITrackedViewController` in both .h and .m files

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
```

It's working fine for some screens but not for some other screens. I'm sending the screen names by using `self.screenName = @"Home screen";`.

NSLogger is as below for the viewcontrollers that successfully integrated,

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:414): Saved hit: {
parameters =     {
    "&_u" = ".etno";
    "&_v" = "mi3.0.1";
    "&an" = My Project;
    "&av" = "1.0";
    "&cd" = "Home Screen";
    "&cid" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    "&sr" = 320x480;
    "&t" = appview;
    "&tid" = "UA-XXXXXXX-2";
    "&ul" = en;
    "&v" = 1;
    "&z" = XXXXXXXXXXXXX;
    gaiVersion = "3.01";
    };
    timestamp = "2014-04-28 09:44:17 +0000";
}
```

But there is no logging for unsuccessfull attempts, after sometime I can see some logging like,

```
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000007
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.01 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 00000000
```

I'd checked with all the viewcontrollers, there is no difference in code while integrating Google-Analytics between those screens.

What am I missing? Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In my app, I send id<GAITracker> tracker = [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker; rv = [tracker sendView:@"myscreen"];. It works well until now.

Comment: @nmh, I'm not using the way that you had used. :(

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you do in self.screenName?

Comment: @nmh, in the GAITrackedViewController.h file ,there is a string named `screenname`. If I send any parameter to that string that will be added in the google analtics data browser.

Comment: I also have this. Also to note, for me it is consistently the same screens which are recorded and same ones that are not recorded.

Comment: Integrate New SDK of GoogleAnalytics your issue will be resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where did you add `self.screenName = @"Home screen";` ?

I used to send the page view event instead of using automatic tracking:

```
//Init once
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 30;
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = NO;
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:gai_id];
```

And in a common UIViewController class (you can then inherit from this class whenever you want to track the page):

1. Define a property  screenName in .h

   @property(nonatomic, copy)   NSString *screenName;
2. Use it in .m

   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       //Google track
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   ```
   @try {
       [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:screenName];
       [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
   }
   @catch (NSException *exception) {
       NSLog(@"[ERROR] in Automatic screen tracking: %@", exception.description);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Remember to set in inherit ViewControllers

   ```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     self.screenName = @"my page name";
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. I'm following the steps in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/). There I can't find a word `kGAIScreenName`.

Comment: Hi, in GA 3.0 you can find the information in GAIDictionaryBuilder.h. It says:/*!
 Returns a GAIDictionaryBuilder object with parameters specific to an appview
 hit.

 Note that using this method will not set the screen name for followon hits.  To
 do that you need to call set:kGAIDescription value:<screenName> on the
 GAITracker instance.
 */
+ (GAIDictionaryBuilder *)createAppView;

Comment: I got your point +1, need to wait for one day for checking. Thankx.

Answer (score 1):

Eva Madrazo's answer gave me an idea that I went to the [GAI tutorial link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) and there I found an another link for [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration).

There I found that,

I need to replace,

```
self.screenName = @"Home screen";
```

with

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Home Screen"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView]  build]];
```

Now all the screens receiving hits in the Google Analytics.
But, I need to import

```
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

to avoid undeclared [identifier error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18480317/756941).